# face book like button is not showing like on facebook account.

Tags: php, facebook, magento, facebook-like

I am using facebook like button. I have taken the code from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

I want user to be able to like products from the cart in magento. Below is my code.

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

With the help of above code liking count is being generated in a proper manner but it is not showing it on facebook that i have liked this page when i click on like.

so what parameter is missing that it is not showing on face book. If any one has the solution kindly tell.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

&amp was missing in href parameter. Due to that it was not sharing it on face book. but only liking. After placing &amp it works in a nice manner.

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ? >&amp; send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```